# Using saved model to process system images results in a freeze

Tags: python, tensorflow

*First of all, this is a student project and I'm not here to ask for you to do it for me, I'm just stuck since a couple of days and couldn't find something to help me on the internet. Unfortunately our teacher can't help us on this topic.*

So, I'm working on an OCR convolutional network, started with [MNIST For ML Beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) to understand the basics of tensorflow and then switched to [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) because I had to go further (92% was really not enough).

At the moment, my model could reach 99.X% of accuracy during training phases, so I decided to start searching how to make it process real images, took some pictures of hand-written digits and added a layer to my NN to process images to resize them to 28*28, then to a [None, 784] tensor to fit my trained model.

Problem is that, when I start this model with my data, the process freezes, with no system stress at all (all cores at 0%, RAM free, tensorflow CPU).

Since the code is a bit fat, I created a gist to make reading easier.

The main file (the one I start with python):

https://gist.github.com/Supamiu/8c31c53141a37ce7da05b5b1135b7bae

And Tools.py:

https://gist.github.com/Supamiu/a5ffcbab8a3b994ed89919fd9b673af6

If you want to see the kind of picture I'm processing, here is an example:
[image]

When I start my main.py files for the first time, it works well because it's the training phase.

Then I start it for the second time, and it freezes right when I call the first `sess.run`, with no system limitation (no CPU usage nor RAM usage).

Comment: Do you have a stack trace from when it freezes (ctrl+c will give you one)? Usually freezes come from queues or other input pipeline problems but I don't see those in your graph.

Comment: I do not have any stack, the process is fully frozen, Ctrl+C doesn't even stop it, I need to send a SIGKILL to the process to stop it. I don't have more informations than the two files I linked.

Comment: Fully frozen is something I haven't seen before. Can you grab a stack trace from gdb?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos Yes I know it's something that should not exist, I checked if I could get any stack trace of something that got an exception or an error... Nothing. I changed the way that I parse the image to parse it without TensorFlow, this way I only provide float arrays and it works well. Thank you for you time :)